# Best and proper way to use Entity Framework in _Layout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a standard ASP.Net template, which has a _Layout where my menu is generated. I have multiple data contexts representing different databases throughout my application and all works fine.

I want to add a count as a bootstrap badge next to one of the items in the _Layout. To do this I need to pass in db.TicketDal.Count(). What is the best way to do this directly into the layout. I did try passing the data in a ViewBag entry from the home controller but then when I go to different controllers that doesn't display. I could modify each controller but that seems the wrong way to do it. I suspect I am overthinking this but any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create a `BaseController`. There you can get the `var TicketCount = db.TicketDal.Count();` or some `List<MenuItems>` let's say and any other controllers must inherit from `BaseController` so in any of them and in any of their methods you would have the same instance of  `List<MenuItems>` or `TicketCount`

Or you can create a helper class.

```
public static class BaseKnowledgeHelper
{
  public static int GetTicketCount()
   {
     return db.TicketDal.Count();
    }
}
```

And call that everywhere: `@BaseKnowledgeHelper.GetTicketCount()`

Comment: Not sure Razvan, seems workable to me. I ended up doing this way because it was much simpler. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am going to suggest what i suggested on a similar post like this.

I would not create a `BaseController`, this would load and query the DB every single time (which could be ok) and the `UI` thread is dependent on the DB call.

What I would do is implement an `Ajax` call to get this information and then put it on your `_Layout`

**Acton Method**

```
public ActionResult GetTicketCount()
{
  //Code to fetch the data for the count
  return Json(count, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

**Ajax on the View**

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetTicketCount","WhatEverController")',
        success: function (data) { 
        // You can now do something with the data which contains the count
        // e.g. Find the div where the count is suppose to be and insert it.
        }
    });
 });
```

This way you are not having to wait for any DB calls to finish, the downside is that the count will not appear at the exact same time as your DOM loads. But you could always make it more friendly looking by using something like [Spin.js](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/)

Comment: And why you give a down vote for my answer? Just because it isn't an optimal one?